# how to have login buttons on the right side with navbar toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have toggled navbar and these two login and sign up buttons on the right side but after adding the navbar toggle it's showing below the navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Readself.in</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Course</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">My profile <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Login -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="clear: both;">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Screen shot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmgvS.png)

Comment: Your Sign Up and Login ul is outside of the div.  Unless you have some custom css changing the default behaviour, divs are display block which makes them take up the full width of their parent.  Inspect the sibling elements and see which ones are taking up the remaining space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `clear:both` from the inline style and put the `ul` inside of `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">`

Here is an working [**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/vLgwmX)

The navbar code should look like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Course</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">My profile <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    <!-- Your ul -->
    </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your sign up and login ul are outside of the `div.navbar-nav` try to make them inside then use `pull-right` to move your content to right

working in this **[PEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKJdmz)**

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate.